# C# xml deserialization ignoring List<> properties unexpectedly

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, .net-4.5

Because XmlSerializer won't work on dictionaries, I use the XmlIgnore attribute on them, and use a mediating List<> property to render the dictionary as a list, which *does* work with serialization. However, my List<> property is ignored on deserialization. (There's no error thrown, and no serialization events are raised.) Why?

```
[XmlIgnore]
public Dictionary<string, string> ConnectionStrings { get; set; }
```

Here is the "surrogate" list property that is supposed to used for de/serialization. Like I say, this works on serialization, but the property is ignored during deserialization. I'm trying to understand why/what to do about it....

```
public List<ConnectionItem> SerializedConnections
{
    get 
    { 
        return ConnectionStrings.Select(keyPair => new ConnectionItem() { Name = keyPair.Key, ConnectionString = keyPair.Value }).ToList(); 
    }
    set 
    {
        ConnectionStrings = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var ci in value) ConnectionStrings.Add(ci.Name, ci.ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

I tried setting a breakpoint in the set accessor of my SerializedConnections property, but it's never hit.

Comment: I don't know why Dictionary isn't serializable, it's not that difficult to do. You can make your own SerializableDictionary class and implement IXmlSerializable to serialize the data. I've done it a few times but I don't have the code handy to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is never going to work like you've assumed. During deserialization, `XmlSerializer` **invokes the getter** to retrieve a presumably empty `List<T>` instance, and then calls its `Add(T item)` method to fill it with deserialized objects.

The [documentation in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer), in particular, says:

> The XmlSerializer gives special treatment to classes that implement `IEnumerable` or `ICollection`. A class that implements `IEnumerable` must implement a public `Add` method that takes a single parameter. The `Add` method's parameter must be of the same type as is returned from the `Current` property on the value returned from `GetEnumerator`, or one of that type's bases. A class that implements `ICollection` (such as `CollectionBase`) in addition to `IEnumerable` must have a public `Item` indexed property (indexer in C#) that takes an integer, and it must have a public `Count` property of type integer. The parameter to the `Add` method must be the same type as is returned from the `Item` property, or one of that type's bases. For classes that implement `ICollection`, values to be serialized are retrieved from the indexed `Item` property, not by calling `GetEnumerator`.

The core issue of your design is that the `SerializedConnections` property behaves *as a data generator*. In other words, every time you invoke the getter a fresh instance is returned. Properties shouldn't work like that—only methods should.

A possible solution is to implement a custom collection implementing `IList<ConnectionItem>` and using a `Dictionary<string, string>` as backing storage. Then the `ConnectionStrings` property, or better a private field, would be of this custom type, and `SerializedConnections` property would behave correctly during serialization/deserialization.